# Why can I not use my QML singleton module?

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

I have a simple test project at https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/font_test

When I build it, I get the error:

> qrc:/main.qml:5 module "Fonts" is not installed

My directory structure looks like:

```
font_test
├── assets
│   └── Fonts
│       ├── Art Brewery.ttf
│       ├── Fonts.qml
│       ├── Roboto-Light.ttf
│       ├── Roboto-Medium.ttf
│       ├── Roboto-Regular.ttf
│       └── qmldir
├── font_test.pro
├── font_test.pro.user
├── main.cpp
├── main.qml
└── qml.qrc
```

my [qml.qrc](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/font_test/blob/main/qml.qrc) file is:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/Fonts">
        <file alias="Art Brewery.ttf">assets/Fonts/Art Brewery.ttf</file>
        <file alias="Roboto-Light.ttf">assets/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf</file>
        <file alias="Roboto-Medium.ttf">assets/Fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf</file>
        <file alias="Roboto-Regular.ttf">assets/Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

my [project file](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/font_test/blob/main/font_test.pro) is:

```
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/assets

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
  assets/Fonts/Fonts.qml \
  assets/Fonts/qmldir
```

My [Fonts.qml](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/font_test/blob/main/assets/fonts/Fonts.qml) file is:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.12

Item
{
  readonly property FontLoader artBrewery: FontLoader { source: "qrc:/Fonts/Art Brewery.ttf" }
  readonly property FontLoader robotoLight: FontLoader { source: "qrc:/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf" }
  readonly property FontLoader robotoMedium: FontLoader { source: "qrc:/Fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf" }
  readonly property FontLoader robotoRegular: FontLoader { source: "qrc:/Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" }
}
```

My [qmldir](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/font_test/blob/main/assets/fonts/qmldir) inside of the assets/fonts folder is:

```
singleton Fonts 1.0 Fonts.qml
```

I try to use the font in [main.qml](https://github.com/jh3010-qt-questions/font_test/blob/main/main.qml)

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

import Fonts 1.0

Window {
  width: 640
  height: 480
  visible: true
  title: qsTr("Hello World")

  Column
  {
    spacing: 8

    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 8

    Label
    {
      text: "DEFAULT: Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs"
    }

    Label
    {
      text: "ART BREWERY: Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs"

      font.family: Fonts.artBrewery.name
      font.pixelSize: 36
    }

    Label
    {
      text: "ROBOTO: Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs"
    }
  }
}
```

Before I added `QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/assets` to my project file, Qt Creator would complain about `import Fonts 1.0`. Does it make sense this would be required?

I am wondering if `assets/fonts/qmldir` belongs in `DISTFILES`...?

I am not sure what needs to be changed so `font.family: Fonts.artBrewery.name` in main.qml will work.

Comment: The folder name and import name do not match casing, is that an error in the question, or how it actually is? They should match

Comment: It was not an error in the question as can be confirmed by visiting the GitHub repo. I have corrected it, but the problem remains. There is something else going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-topic.html#defining-a-qml-module), the module has to be available in the QML engine's import path:

> To define a module, a developer should gather together the various QML documents, JavaScript resources and C++ plugins which belong in the module into a single directory, and write an appropriate module definition qmldir file which should also be placed into the directory. The directory can then be installed into the QML import path as a module.

You can do this by calling [addImportPath()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#addImportPath) with the path to the parent directory of the directory that contains the `qmldir`. When you import your module with

```
import Fonts 1.0
```

the QML engine looks through each import path for a directory called `Fonts`, and if it finds it, looks for a `qmldir` file. Since you use a prefix in your QRC file, the final path to the `qmldir` file is `:/Fonts/qmldir`. The parent directory of `Fonts` (the directory that contains the `qmldir`) is the root resource directory `:/`, so:

```
diff --git a/main.cpp b/main.cpp
index 3d80569..de4efb7 100644
--- a/main.cpp
+++ b/main.cpp
@@ -10,6 +10,7 @@ int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
 
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
+  engine.addImportPath(":/");
   const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
   QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                    &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
```

You also need to ensure that all of the files your module uses are available as resources. That means adding the following files:

```
diff --git a/qml.qrc b/qml.qrc
index f212706..40cb8dc 100644
--- a/qml.qrc
+++ b/qml.qrc
@@ -3,6 +3,8 @@
         <file>main.qml</file>
     </qresource>
     <qresource prefix="/Fonts">
+        <file alias="qmldir">assets/Fonts/qmldir</file>
+        <file alias="Fonts.qml">assets/Fonts/Fonts.qml</file>
         <file alias="Art Brewery.ttf">assets/Fonts/Art Brewery.ttf</file>
         <file alias="Roboto-Light.ttf">assets/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf</file>
         <file alias="Roboto-Medium.ttf">assets/Fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf</file>
```

Comment: Great. That works. I am surprised that QML_IMPORT_PATH does not serve the same purpose as engine.addImportPath. I removed QML_IMPORT_PATH from the .pro file and also removed DISTFILES += from the .pro file.

Comment: Have you tried using `QML2_IMPORT_PATH `?

Comment: I just did and it works as well. I think I like that solution better then a line of c++ code. I suppose the c++ solution would be better in cases where other factors influence the paths that can only be known and determined by code.

Comment: No! `QML_IMPORT_PATH` / `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` are **only** for QtCreator. It makes QtCreator recognize the modules, autocomplete their contents, and not red-underline all of them as errors. `QML_IMPORT_PATH` exists because QtCreator cannot execute C++ code to know where modules are. If you do not use `engine.addImportPath()` it will only work when started from within QtCreator, or if you run it from a batch script that explicitly sets QML2_IMPORT_PATH beforehand. This is a bad idea. If you are using this method you need BOTH engine.addImportPath() for runtime AND `QML_IMPORT_PATH` for QtCreator.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thank you for that additional information.

Comment: The difference seems to be that `QML_IMPORT_PATH` is only recognized by QtCreator but `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` is recognized by the executable. However it still remains inside the `.pro` file and is not compiled into said executable - QtCreator just pushes it to the executable when `Run` or `Debug` buttons are pressed. If you run the exe (on Windows you need either copy Qt libraries to same directory or set up PATH variable to them) the `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` is not there unless you assign it via `set` command before running the executable. This adds another needless step, so it should be avoided.

Comment: I still have ```import Fonts 1.0``` in main.qml, however, Qt Creator is complaining that the module is not found. The application still runs. I am assuming that this is a bug or am I still missing some detail?

Comment: Does QtCreator not read `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`? Okay, set `QML_IMPORT_PATH` to your project path and it should work - I haven't tested this method.

Comment: Ok. Went back to ```QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/assets``` and Qt Creator no longer complains. Appears everything is working as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I see another answer beat me in a couple of minutes. Oh well. I'll post mine just in case.

#### How to fix the problem through directory import:

1. Add missing files to resource list in `qml.qrc` file:

   ```
   <qresource prefix="/Fonts">
    ...........
     <file alias="Fonts.qml">assets/Fonts/Fonts.qml</file>
     <file alias="qmldir">assets/Fonts/qmldir</file>
   ```

please note the `alias`es, otherwise paths will be different

If you do not add the files to resources, they won't be visible through `qrc://`, and also they won't be included into your compiled application i.e. your code will only run on your computer unless you install missing files manually with your application

2. Remove module import from `main.qml`:

   ```
   //import Fonts 1.0
   ```

This is not needed (and will not work) if you create your singleton through `qmldir` file

The import won't work because Qt won't be looking for modules within `qrc://` path unless you explicitly specify so in C++ code - see the other answer on how to do that

3. Instead add a [directory import](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html) to the top of `main.qml`:

   ```
   import "qrc:/Fonts/"
   ```

this imports [`qmldir` file](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html) which creates a singleton named `Fonts` from file `Fonts.qml` as you specified

Please note that although it imports `qmldir` and `*.qml` ***files*** inside the directory, it does not tell Qt to load ***modules*** from that same directory.

4. I also had to add `QT += qml` to `font_test.pro` but it's probably not needed for your version of Qt/QML if it compiles at all
5. Use your singleton like you are already trying to do: `Fonts.artBrewery.name`

#### References

See Qt documentation for more information:

- [QML directory import](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html) including [directory definition `qmldir` files](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html#directory-listing-qmldir-files)
- [module definition `qmldir` files](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the directory import. Perhaps you want to link to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks. References added at the end of the answer.

Comment: Great. That works. I am surprised that QML_IMPORT_PATH does not serve the same purpose as engine.addImportPath. I removed QML_IMPORT_PATH from the .pro file and also removed DISTFILES += from the .pro file. Strangely, placing ```import Fonts 1.0``` does allow it work, but Qt Creator complains the module is not found. I am guessing this is a bug. Using ```import "qrc:/Fonts/"``` works as well and is the correct solution.

Comment: In my case, I think ```QML2_IMPORT_PATH``` in the .pro file is the better solution. The documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html is also relevant to this question